# Dynamically adding data while reaching end of the Scroll positon

Tags: gxt

```
         To limit the number of records fetched, I plan to add more records when we reach the end of the data in an EditorTreeGrid . I have tried the following code
```

myTree.addListener(Events.BodyScroll,new Listener() {

```
     @Override
```

public void handleEvent(GridEvent be) {

```
                  //I need to check if the scroll has reached the end to the list and 
                    then add more records to the store .
```

EditorTreeGrid  component = be.getComponent();
   System.out.println(be.getScrollTop()); 
                        // The above always seems to
                        //change as I change the pace of my scrolls .

}

Please help .
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using a LiveGrid and modified the same to support an editable grid.